# Lets Encrypt SSL setup in bitnami.conf in AWS Lightsail

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, lets-encrypt, bitnami

I created a new Instance in AWS Lightsail and Configured a domain `example.com` which has 2 subdomains as well. `test.example.com` and `app.example.com`.

I removed the default `bitnami.conf` and created a new one. This removed the predefined SSL setup code. I installed Lets encrypt by following this [tutorial](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-lamp).

Here is my `bitnami.conf` file before adding SSL. I could access all the websites as desired.

```
ServerName example.com

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example.com
       <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/default_website>
                                     DirectoryIndex index.html
                                     AllowOverride All
                                     Require all granted
                     </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/default_website
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app_website
    <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app_website>
                                     DirectoryIndex index.html
                                     AllowOverride All
                                     Require all granted
                     </Directory>
    ServerName app.example.com

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/test_website
     <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/test_website>
                                     DirectoryIndex index.html
                                     AllowOverride All
                                     Require all granted
                     </Directory>
    ServerName test.example.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my `bitnami.conf` file after adding SSL code. Redirection from `example.com` to `https://example.com` works fine, but the page doesn't load in `https`. I'm getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

New `bitnami.conf` file

```
ServerName example.com

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example.com
    RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
            RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

       <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/default_website>
                                     DirectoryIndex index.html
                                     AllowOverride All
                                     Require all granted
                     </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/default_website
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/default_website"
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key"

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/default_website">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3 >
Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>

# Error Documents
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

# Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app_website
    <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app_website>
                                     DirectoryIndex index.html
                                     AllowOverride All
                                     Require all granted
                     </Directory>
    ServerName app.example.com
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/test_website
     <Directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/test_website>
                                     DirectoryIndex index.html
                                     AllowOverride All
                                     Require all granted
                     </Directory>
    ServerName test.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here. You also need to define the new port in which Apache will start to listen and the different cyphers and protocols it will accept. These lines are included in the bitnami.conf file we include in our stacks by default

```
Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH !RC4"
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
```

> You will need to include them before defining the VirtualHost for the port 443

I hope this helps

Comment: This worked. But the https still shows insecure. Is there any way I can make it secure?

Comment: You will be probably running into a mixed content issue. That means that you have some http links when accessing https. This is probably caused by some images or CSS files you are using in your website. You will need to change them to use https to solve the issue.